# Замена значений полей (база данных)

Tags: sql, база-данных

Требуется заменить значение id книги, на id автора этой книги.

Структура данных для запроса

[image: Структура данных]

В таблице RegistrationOfIssuance записывается кто когда взял или вернул книгу. В таблице BookInfo в целом информация о книге, а в Authors ФИО авторов. Нужно найти более популярного автора. Как составить SQL запрос?

Сделал по совету коментатора и вот что вышло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT RegistrationOfIssuance.Id, RegistrationOfIssuance.DateOperation, RegistrationOfIssuance.Operation, Count(BooksInfo.IdAuthor) AS [Count-IdAuthor]

FROM (Authors INNER JOIN BooksInfo ON Authors.Id = BooksInfo.IdAuthor) INNER JOIN RegistrationOfIssuance ON BooksInfo.Id = RegistrationOfIssuance.IdNumberBook

GROUP BY RegistrationOfIssuance.Id, RegistrationOfIssuance.DateOperation, RegistrationOfIssuance.Operation

ORDER BY Count(BooksInfo.IdAuthor) DESC;
```

Comment: *Требуется заменить значение id книги, на id автора этой книги.* o_O Так все связи же развалятся!

Comment: *Нужно найти более популярного автора. Как составить SQL запрос?* Связать все таблицы, сгруппировать по автору, посчитать количества, отсортировать по убыванию, взять первую запись WITH TIES.

Comment: @Akina Я сделал так как, но он не считает. Изменю вопрос и добавлю итоговые скриншоты

Comment: СУБД укажите, что ли... MS Access, что ли?

Comment: @Akina Простите, не указал. Да это MS Access

Comment: *он не считает.* Синтаксически к запросу претензий нет, так что считать он обязан. Другой вопрос - что именно он считает... а считает он операции с книгами. Тогда как по логике популярность - это сколько раз книгу **брали** - так что считать надо только записи, где `Operation = 'Взял'`. Наверное... PS. MS Access, кстати, не поддерживает WITH TIES... так что запрос вернёт одну какую-то из наиболее популярных. Если нужны все - требуется подзапрос, считающий количество для наиболее популярных.

Comment: @Akina На форуме нашёл ответ. В ответе на этот вопрос я укажу, то что нашёл и то что подойдёт для моей задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итог:
Для нахождения автора, чьи книги больше берут нужно сделать запрос:

```
SELECT Authors.FIO, Count(Authors.FIO) AS CountOfFIO
FROM (Authors INNER JOIN BooksInfo ON Authors.ID = BooksInfo.IdAuthor) INNER JOIN RegistrationOfIssuance ON BooksInfo.ID = RegistrationOfIssuance.IdNumberBook
GROUP BY Authors.FIO;
```

В моём случае нужно найти за текущий год и в таблице RegistrationOfIssuance из-за того что берут и отдают книги, книга отмечается дважды, поэтому я взял только те варианты когда берут книгу.

```
SELECT Authors.FIO, Count(Authors.FIO) AS CountOfFIO
FROM (Authors INNER JOIN BooksInfo ON Authors.ID = BooksInfo.IdAuthor) INNER JOIN RegistrationOfIssuance ON BooksInfo.ID = RegistrationOfIssuance.IdNumberBook
WHERE (([RegistrationOfIssuance].[DateOperation]>=#1/1/2021#))
GROUP BY Authors.FIO, RegistrationOfIssuance.Operation
HAVING (((RegistrationOfIssuance.Operation) Like "Взял"))
ORDER BY Count(Authors.FIO) DESC;
```

Прикрепляю ссылку на форум, где [помогли](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1335608-a/podschyot-poley)